# type object 'Circuit' has no attribute 'from_ops'

Tags: quantum-circuit, cirq

I am working on a Cirq notebook and the quantum circuit is created in this way:

```
import cirq
import numpy as np

from cirq import GridQubit, Circuit

from cirq import Simulator
simulator = Simulator()

q = GridQubit(0,0)
circuit = Circuit.from_ops(
    cirq.measure(q, key='m')
)
```

and I receive an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Circuit' has no attribute 'from_ops'
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from_ops` was [deprecated](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/2181) a long time ago. You can just call `cirq.Circuit(*ops)` like

```
import cirq
import numpy as np

from cirq import GridQubit, Circuit

from cirq import Simulator
simulator = Simulator()

q = GridQubit(0,0)
circuit = Circuit(
    cirq.measure(q, key='m')
)
```

instead.